# admin search of pages returns custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, search

I was looking for a particular page today and got search results that surprised me. Here's what happened:

- start on Dashboard->Pages->All Pages
- search "standard"

  - URL= http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s=standard&post_status=all&post_type=page&action=-1&m=0&paged=1&action2=-1
- get list of some pages, some posts, some custom posts of types ash_dyeing and ash_loomsong
- try searching a different term and receive error message: "Invalid post type"

So I wondered if all the admin post searches were wonky.  I tried again from

- Dashboard->Posts->All Posts

  - http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s=standard&post_status=all&post_type=post&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1
  - posts, pages and custom post types returned
- Dashboard->Dyeing Samples->All Dyeing Samples

  - http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s=standard&post_status=all&post_type=ash_dyeing&action=-1&m=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1
  - posts, pages and custom post types returned

As you can see, all the urls are the same except for post_type=X, which appears to be ignored.  Why might that happen and how can I fix it?

System details:

-wp 3.3.1
-theme: Suffusion 3.9.6 with child theme

ETA:

Turns out this *is* a plugin problem, specifically Events Manager 5.0.51.  It can be resolved by setting  the plugin's 'Include in WordPress Searches?' option to 'yes'

Comment: If you found the answer, post it as an **answer** (and then *accept* that answer, by clicking the checkmark), rather than editing your **question** with that information.

Comment: @Chip Bennett: I tried to do that.  It told me I didn't have enough rep to answer my own question. Sigh.

Comment: You've got 74 Rep? Hmm... you *should* be able to do that...

Comment: Coincidently, that was the plug-in that was playing up on my test install too. When altering the query for searches, the plug-in author has probably neglected to check `is_admin()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what's actually causing the issue, but it isn't WordPress. Try deactivating all themes and plug-ins, a reactivating them one by one until the problem occurs to isolate the plug-in/theme responsible. You'll have to contact the developer and they may look into it for you.